# Changing button functions on a form

Tags: 2007

I'm fairly new with sharepoint so go easy on me. We have a set of modules that we want the user to acknowledge they've read. What ideally we want it to do is open up a separate window to the form fields for the list (so far so easy) BUT, when the form pops up, the usual options are ok/cancel and then it takes you to the sharepoint list it just populated. What I'd like to happen is to change the function of the OK button to automatically close the window. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What form is popping up? Just not sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create more robust forms that the simple entry form SharePoint uses by default, you could create an InfoPath 2007 browser form. InfoPath offers a lot more options for creating forms.